# Not receiving push notifications from GCM (Android)

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using this [link](https://rails-push-notifications-test.herokuapp.com/android) to test my push notifications. Last night it worked fine, woke up this morning and I'm no longer receiving push notifications. I tested it before I wrote any new code. The device used for testing is a Samsung Galaxy S5, OS is Lollipop.

Here is my manifest, let me know if you need to see any of my services.

```
<permission
        android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        ....
        ....

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.fullpackage.name.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".services.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I get no errors and it says the message is sent successfully from both my server and that testing link above. I've tried uninstalling the app and generating a new token, and its still not working. I am also able to retrieve my token successfully each time I load the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client). Seems you missed to add you package name to permissions.

```
<permission
    android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Also sources of yours MyGcmListenerService and MyInstanceIDListenerService would be useful to help (how you obtain and handle token etc).

Or, if you say that its worked fine yesterday, try to enable and then disable airplane mode, or reboot the phone.

Comment: I've tried it both ways. The quick `.permission.C2D_MESSAGE` and the full description of `my.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE`. The tutorial has been read thoroughly

Comment: rebooting the device was all i needed. Thanks!

Comment: So using a "." as the beginning is ok, right? If so, how come when checking that the permission is granted, it says it's not granted? I've asked about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33463556/878126

Comment: using a "." as the beginning is NOT ok here