# How come a GCM permission isn't granted on Android 6?

Tags: android, permissions, google-cloud-messaging, android-6.0-marshmallow

### Background

I'm trying to investigate what an app at the office needs to change about its permissions, in order to support Android 6 nicely.

### The problem

I've found which permission needs confirmation and which isn't, except for one :

```
<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

It seems that this permission isn't mentioned anywhere that I look for, as one that's not granted automatically and yet I can't find where the user can enable it as a confirmation.

### What I tried

In order to find which permissions are granted by default and which aren't , I just called this code:

```
private void checkPermissionsOfApp(String packageName) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        final ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Log.d("AppLog", "Listing all permissions of app with PackageName: " + applicationInfo.packageName);
        PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        //Get Permissions
        String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
        if (requestedPermissions != null) {
            for (String permission : requestedPermissions) {
                boolean permissionGranted = pm.checkPermission(permission, packageName) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                Log.d("AppLog", "permission:" + permission + " permissionGranted:" + permissionGranted);
            }
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the call:

```
checkPermissionsOfApp(getPackageName());
```

Using the above code, it crashes for the problematic permission, but when using ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission it says it's not granted.

### The question

How could it be?
How can I grant the app this permission?
Is it mentioned anywhere?

Comment: What *precisely* is "this permission"? What is its `protectionLevel`?

Comment: I don't know whether this comment would help you or not, but I remember that Google announced at I/O 2015 that permissions will be granted at run time in Android M.

Comment: @CommonsWare The permission is written in the question. I accidentally didn't format it.

Comment: Off the cuff, that doesn't look like a valid permission name. Once upon a time, you needed an app-specific custom permission for GCM, one that blended in your package name. IIRC, that was a `signature` permission, and `signature` permissions are not part of the runtime permission system. They are granted automatically based upon signature matches. But I haven't messed with GCM in a couple of years.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's the weird thing. I don't remember this permission, and it's weird that it starts with "." . Do you think it's not even needed?

Comment: @android developer this permission to prevent other Android applications from registering and receiving the Android application's messages. The permission name must exactly match this pattern—otherwise the Android application will not receive the messages.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: @yashodhandivakaran According to what we've noticed so far, it does work, for quite a long time, so the "." in the beginning is valid, as it adds the packageName before. However, when I do it myself when checking, it fails/crashes to check if the permission is granted.

Comment: Using a POC, on Android 6, it crashes for pm.checkPermission , yet on Android 5.1, it doesn't (yet still says it's not granted). I will now check it on the real app.

Comment: @android developer I just checked it with this code 
  if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,"<package>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.e("Permission C2D","granted");
        }else {
            Log.e("Permission C2D","not granted");
        }

It shows granted but if I use ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" without package name then it shows "not granted"

Comment: @yashodhandivakaran How odd. So it's a bug in the API then?

Comment: @android developer I just tried with ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,"dummy text") and it gave me "not granted". Not sure how this check is done

Comment: @yashodhandivakaran I've changed the permission to one that has the package name at the beginning, and it still says that it's not granted. However, after declaring it in a new tag it worked :     <permission android:name="com.example.user.androidmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client), which was updated in October of 2015, still indicates that you need the signature permission.

See also [Not receiving push notifications from GCM (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133277/not-receiving-push-notifications-from-gcm-android)

As @CommonsWare mentioned, this does not appear to be part of the new runtime permission checking, or at least is not considered a "dangerous" permission, and so should be automatically granted.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I'm not sure why it is this way, but the permission is said to be granted only if :

1. The package name of the app is its prefix
2. you also declare the permission, as such:

   ```
   <permission
      android:name="com.example.user.androidmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
       android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
   ```

The weird thing is that even though the code said that the permission is not granted when not adding the package name, it worked on the app.